# Condition for empty dataframe is not satisfied

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I make queries that I store in a dataframe and then send them to a dictionary, for this it is obvious that the dataframe only contains one record. When there is no information I do something like:

```
if not df.empty:
    data_q.update({'revenue_week': '{:,}'.format(df.iloc[0].column-name)})
else:
    data_q.update({'revenue_week': 0})
```

My purpose is that when there are no values, to replace it with `0`. But doing so it still indicates the dataframe is empty.

Comment: Hello mendizabal, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you post/edit your question to include the head of your DataFrame, `df.head(5)`, so we can better help you? Thanks!

Comment: This part feels like it wouldn't work.  Python generally doesn't like hyphens in names.  Have you tried using .loc() not iloc()?  That would mean you could try `df.loc[0, 'column-name']`.